# Getting ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android

I am getting ActivityNotFoundException though i register the Activity class in the Manifest file.
Can you help me please...

Thanks..

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="Login"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Registration" android:label="Registration"
    ></activity>
     <activity android:name=".Dashboard" android:label="Dashboard"
    ></activity>
     <activity android:name="com.innominds.BillDetails" 
    ></activity>
</application>
```

This the Manifest file.

Now I wrote the below code for BillDetails class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class BillDetails extends FragmentActivity
{

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.details_bill);
 }

  public static class BillSearch extends Fragment
   {
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
         {
             return inflater.inflate(R.layout.billsearch, container, false);
         }

         public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) 
         {
              super.onActivityCreated(savedState);
         }
   }

    public static class DetailBill extends Fragment
    {
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
         {
             return inflater.inflate(R.layout.billdetails, container, false);
         }

         public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) 
         {
              super.onActivityCreated(savedState);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to post your AndroidManifest and the code you use to call the Activity..

Comment: Check for typos. Then post your code and your manifest.

Comment: Without looking at your code, even yoda will refuse to help :), Please give us some codes so we can have a look and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<activity android:name="yourPackage.YourActivity" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your activity in a different package than the application package? If so, then in the manifest file enter the activity's full package name.

Comment: In the manifest file, i write like this--- <activity android:name=".BillDetails" android:label="BillDetails"
        ></activity>

Comment: But my Bill Details class is extending FragmentActivity. is it the reason for getting the exception???

Comment: There is really no way to tell what is wrong without showing us anything.